# How to use the escapeSingleQuotes method?

Tags: soql, security, dynamic-soql

I'm trying to use this method in a dynamic SOQL query. Follow the sample code:

```
public static String getRowById(String sobjName, id id) {
    String query = 'SELECT ';            
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields =
        Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for (String f : objectFields.keySet()) {
        query += f;
        query += ',';
    }

    query = query.substring(0, query.length() - 1);
    query += ' FROM '+ sobjName;
    query += ' WHERE id = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(id) + '\'';
    query += ' LIMIT 1';

    return query;
}
```

The problem is that this is still considered as a SOQL Injection vulnerability.

Am I missing something here? I also tried to use it as a parameter like this:

```
getRowById('SFT_Brand__c',
    String.escapeSingleQuotes(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')));
```

Comment: I'd consider the `sobjName` argument to be the bigger injection risk if it is coming from the query string parameters. Also, I'd be surprised in the Id type could contain single quote characters. Look at validating if sobjName is a valid sObject?

Comment: @DanielBallinger: but doesn't the use of `sObjName` in the `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` call verify it's valid?  It would throw an exception there if it wasn't.  If OP is always hard-coding the object name in his calls, I can't see an injection vulnerability.

Comment: @tomlogic: Yes, I think you are correct. `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjName)` returns null for an unknown type.

Comment: When SQL injection succeeds, can you give us the value of `query` variable using System.debug?

Comment: Value of query: `select id,sft_brand_component_type__c,name,isdeleted,sft_brand_tire_type__c,createddate,sft_brand_vehicle_type__c,systemmodstamp,ownerid,lastmodifiedbyid,createdbyid,lastmodifieddate from SFT_Brand__c where id = 'a04U0000006id9NIAQ' limit 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using it correctly.  Here's a simplified version of your script, using the new `String.join()` method and all of the string concatenations in one statement instead of spread out over multiple statements.

```
public static String getRowById(String sobjName, Id id) {
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields =
        Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    return 'SELECT ' + String.join( objectFields.keySet(), ', ')
           + ' FROM ' + sObjName
           + ' WHERE Id = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(Id) + '\''
           + ' LIMIT 1';
}
```

You are correctly escaping the `id` parameter, but that might not even be necessary, since it's an `Id` and not a `String`.

This looks to me like a false positive by the security scan.  If someone disagrees, they should provide a sample exploit that:

- Doesn't throw an exception when `sObjName` is used to get the field list.
- Accepts an invalid Id (15 or 18-character alphanumeric) as the second parameter.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding `with sharing` to the class definition so that the user doesn't get sObject access beyond their permissions. Maybe check if `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjName)` returns null, indicating an unknown sObjName?

Answer (score 0):

The join method produces an error, because of the use of a Set. So I converted it into List and it works fine:

```apex
public static String getRowById(String sobjName, Id id) {
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields =
        Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
      list<string> fieldList =new list<fields>(objectFields.keySet());
    return 'SELECT ' + String.join( fieldList, ', ')
           + ' FROM ' + sObjName
           + ' WHERE Id = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(Id) + '\''
           + ' LIMIT 1';
}
```