# Facing a query exception(System.QueryException: unexpected token: LIKE)?

Tags: apex

```
String accountQuery = 'SELECT Name, Phone, Website, BillingState FROM Account ';
if(searchString != '' && searchString != null) {
        accountQuery += 'WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + searchString + '%\'';
        listAccounts = Database.Query(accountQuery);
}
```

Comment: Can you debug `accountQuery` and post it? It will be easier to see what's wrong with the query if you can actually see it.

Comment: it's all there. just the variable definitions are missing. I added an assumption into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with you code I can see. After adding the variables, I run this using execute anonymous and got fine results. No error:

```
String searchString = 'a';
Account[] listAccounts;
String accountQuery = 'SELECT Name, Phone, Website, BillingState FROM Account ';
if(searchString != '' && searchString != null) {
        accountQuery += 'WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + searchString + '%\'';
        listAccounts = Database.Query(accountQuery);
}
```

But searchString is a loose end.

Please make sure, that your search string does not contain bad characters. Therefore you should escape it properly, e.g. with String.escapeSingleQuotes() - look here: [How to use the escapeSingleQuotes method?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/how-to-use-the-escapesinglequotes-method)

Comment: Put the code somewhere and execute it anonymous. You will see no errors. So it's NOT the code you are showing here - except a possible illegal search string. **So thats my final answer.** If the problem persists, you need to past the entire source code (full vf-page, controller, etc)

Comment: To debug code and following the errors on a vf-page is a nightmare. Use Execute Anonymous (e.g. in the Force.com IDE or in CodeFusion)

Comment: Especially we see no displayaccounts variable in your code. Is it maybe a new question? If so, close this one by picking an answer and open a new one and provide the relevant code. **Please do not overload this single question.**

Comment: If it helped can you vote + close this question please? Thx