# SOQL Injection protection

Tags: soql-injection, escape

I'm facing an issue on code scanning. The following code has second order error.

```
TestList = [SELECT Id, name, address FROM Object__c where Id IN: TestIddSet];
```

TestList is a list of the Object__c.
TestIddSet is a set of ids

I made it into a dynamic query instead, because I found out that using **escapeSingleQuotes** passes code review.

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, name, address FROM Object__c where Id IN: TestIddSet';
TestList = database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(queryString));
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: what was an original issue that security scanner displayed?

Comment: It says as "Second Order SOQL SOSL Injection"

Comment: Is there any more information in the scan results? I thought the first query was fully protected from injection attacks and was generally a cleaner approach than using escapeSingleQuotes. If this was my code, I'd book a [Security Office Hours](https://security.secure.force.com/security/contact/ohours) meeting to get an explanation.

Comment: Calling `escapeSingleQuotes does *nothing*. Except maybe appease naive scanner technology.

Comment: I think it is false positive -- you already have set of ID, and it impossible to do injection. Check this answer -- http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/how-to-use-the-escapesinglequotes-method. In case, if TestIddSet is set of string, you can escape that one by one, but you already have ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a false positive here. I'm not sure what type `TestIddSet` is, but if it's `Set<String>` consider changing it to `Set<Id>`, that way there can be no injection and if for some reason the scanner flags this you can definitely get it discarded as a false-positive.

The scanner is not perfect and I've had to get a few false positives dismissed in the past by having phone calls with the security review team.

Comment: TestIddSet  is of type Set<Id>. Also, I wrote a mail to securecloud@salesforce.com. Turned out to be false positive. Thanks for your help!